# Congruence relation I'm having trouble with

Tags: number-theory, congruences, cryptography

I have this specific congruence relation, and although solving it with a calculator is trivial, I'd like to know what strategy I can use to solve this by hand.

The relation is

> $79^7 \equiv x \mod 403$.

(I also have two other similar problems, but I assume they will be about the same in terms of solving.)

I've looked at Fermat's little theorem, but haven't been able to successfully apply it to this problem, though I suspect that would be the most likely candidate.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The fact that $403=(13)(31)$ may simplify things, Note that $79$ is kind of special modulo $13$.

Comment: I follow what you're saying. Am I correct in saying that:

A =(congruent) B (mod x1 * x2) 

is equivalent to

A =(congruent) B (mod x1) 

When both x1 and x2 are primes? And what is this statement called/how can I find out more about it online?

Comment: For the congruence,mod $31$, compute. Fermat will not be useful, it is good for reducing exponents but the exponent  is already very small. If you are good at arithmetic you can do it in your head.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by your first sentence, "For the congruence, mod 31, compute"?

...Can you point me to some online resource that can explain this?

Comment: We know that $x\equiv 1\pmod{13}$. Now we want to compute $79^7$ modulo $31$. Take advantage of facts such as $79\equiv 17\pmod{31}$, ot $79\equiv -14\pmod{31}$ to simplify the arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

In general (when fermat's little theorem is not applicable, or there is not some nice trick) we do the following. Since $79^2$ is larger than 403, reduce it mod 403. We know that $79^7=79^279^279^279$. You can replace every $79^2$ with its value reduced mod 403. Call this value $y$. You problem is now reducing $y^379$ modulo 403. See if $y^2$ is bigger than 403, if it is, perform the aforementioned process again. If not, work with $y^3$ and then finish the problem by reducing by that value times 79 modulo 403.